# Trouble understanding a VBA snippet; Changing the code to allow multiple inputs from only one input

Tags: vba

I'm having trouble understanding a VBA function.  The code snippet and my questions are below:

```
Sub PullItem()

Dim PurchOrder As CimObjectVariable
--What does this next line do? The customer is using CIMPLICITY graphics
Set PurchOrder = CimGetScriptOwner().GetVariable("PurchOrder")

' SQL Connection String
    Set oADOConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set oADORecords = CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")

    oADOConn.ConnectionString =  PointGet("SQL.INST") & PointGet("SQL.connStr") 
    oADOConn.Open

'If the connection failed to open, we exit the script
    If oADOConn.State <> 1 Then
        LogStatus IT_FAILURE,"","Failed to Connect to SQL Server"
        End
    End If

    --This is all done on a single screen
    --There's a block of 30 purchase orders
    --As it is you can select all of them or only one of them
    --Supposedly that's what this next block of code is doing
    --What I need this code to do is allow the customer to select
    --between 1 and 10 purchase orders
    --So can you explain what is happening here and how I can accomplish
    --what I need?
    If PurchOrder = "AllPOs" Then  
         pOrder = "%"
    Else pOrder = ProdOrder 
    End If

    SQLQuery = "EXEC [dbo].[GetPO] @PurchOrder = '" & pOrder & "'"  

    oADORecords.Open SQLQuery, oADOConn
```

The rest of the code is just manipulating the variable.  That will need some work, too, but one step at a time.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `CIMPLICITY` at all, but it looks like you'll need to configure the user interface there.  Looks like there's documentation [here](http://proscada.ru/cimplicity/) though.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the script is trying to reference the `PurchOrder` variable in the Cimplicity object that called the script (probably a button on the screen or other graphical object).

`Set PurchOrder = CimGetScriptOwner().GetVariable("PurchOrder")`

Without actually seeing the application, my guess is that the selecting purchase orders on the screen runs a script that sets the a global screen variable `PurchOrder`.  The script you've posted is just taking the value in that variable and pulling the data from the database by executing a stored procedure.